# What is the exponential (or geometric) rule (or law) for uranium enrichment?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, nuclear-engineering, isotopes

Uranium ore starts at about .72% U-235...

At ~20% U-235, it is considered to be about '90% of the way' to weapons-grade uranium, which is about ~90% U-235...

Because uranium enrichment in centrifuges follows a geometric (or exponential) law...

I have read about this repeatedly when hearing about Iran's enrichment program....

Does anybody know what the 'rule' or 'equation' is for uranium enrichment...

(I am not trying to build a bomb, I swear....)

Edit: P.S.:

In the Work equation $W_extract = -T R ln(x)$ , what are T, R, and x?

I can find that equation nowhere else....

Comment: "I am not trying to build a bomb, I swear" that is what a person trying to build a bomb would say

Answer (score 4):

You are basically trying to sort the atoms, reducing entropy. The minimum work per mole of extracting an element that has mole fraction $x$ is
$$W_{extract}=-TR\ln(x).$$
So, the cost difference as you go from $x$ to $2x$ is (assuming $x<1/2$) $$W_{extract}(2x)-W_{extract}(x)=-TR\ln(2).$$ Which is constant, as the exponential law says.

Now, for a mixture of two isotopes we need to account for the work of separating each. $$W_{allextract} = -TR \sum_i x_i \ln(x_i)$$ So for two isotopes the  total energy cost is $$W=-TR [x\ln(x)+(1-x)\ln(1-x)]$$ which has a maximum for $x=1/2$ (maximal entropy). At this point the reader may well get suspicious: why is it getting *easier* as $x\rightarrow 1$? The answer is that the above formula assumes a process that keeps entropy constant and is close to reversible. This is a bad approximation as we approach the limit, unless we also want the process to take a very, very long time. [For imperfect separation and irreversible processes the cost is higher](https://doi.org/10.1023/B:OPSY.0000009555.63816.86).

Comment: Thank you!  But... What are R and T, precisely?  I can't find that equation elsewhere...

Comment: T is temperature and R is the gas constant. You will find the equation when googling for enthalphy of mixing or separation.

Answer (score 2):

The exponential law for enrichment is that doubling the percentage of U-235 requires the same amount of effort regardless how much there already is. Getting from 20% to 40% is just as hard as getting from 1% to 2%.

Though obviously, this only works well when the percentage is below half. Getting from 95% to 99% is a lot of work. In this regime, the law goes the other way, i.e. halving the remaining amount of U-238 requires the same amount of work, regardless how much remains.

Comment: I don't think that is valid, at least it seems to me that it can't hold for percentages close to 100%. It should be exponentially harder to enrich U-235 when it is already of weapons-grade quality.

Comment: Addressing the updated version of the answer: there must be some smooth transition between the two laws at about ~50% enrichment. I think OP is asking whether the shape of this graph is known

Answer (score 2):

The equation you are looking for is the SWU calculation (Separative Work Units).  The calculations are described at:

https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Separative_work_unit

Figure 1 shows the exponential dependence that you describe.  Enriching from natural to 4-5% takes more energy then going from 4-5% to 95%.